# How to render page content using Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid

Is it possible to render content of a page (presumably multiple let us say image+text articles) using Fluid? I would like to have more control over the html (Is it a valid reason?). I tried to fetch something I thought could be an array of some objects (rows) via TypoScript, but when assigned to a variable and used in fluid:for it results in a string and therefore a type error, so this does not work:

```
arr = COA
arr.10 = CONTENT
arr.10 {   
  table = tt_content
  select {  
    languageField=sys_language_uid
    where = colNum = 1
  }
}

<f:for each="{arr}" as="article" iteration="itemIteration">
abcd
</f:for>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that out of the box. But the extension "[vhs](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/vhs)" enables you to do so, have a look at the [RenderViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Content/RenderViewHelper.html).

This would get you the first 10 contents on colPos 0 of page 5 and stores them in the variable contentElements. You then iterate through the content objects:

```
<v:content.render column="0" limit="10" pageUid="5" as="contentElements">
  <f:for each="{contentElements}" as="contentElement">
    <f:format.html>{contentElement.bodytext}</f:format.html>
  </f:for>
</v:content.render>
```

Comment: Thanks, it probably brings me closer to what I need, but the code you posted, even with the closing format tag fixed, does not output anything. I guess that's because contentElement is a string and does not have the property bodytext. <f:format.raw>{contentElement}</f:format.raw> works, but renders the same html I would get with TypoScript, so I do not have any more control over the structure than before.

Comment: The alternative version which returns raw content records is `v:content.get` - same arguments as `v:content.render`.

Comment: The above link is on a seoparking site. I assume this is the new site for the render view helper: https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Content/RenderViewHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set render="false" ! Then it works even with html format

```
<v:content.render column="0" pageUid="5" render="false" as="listItem">
                <f:for each="{listItem}" as="contentElement">
                    <f:format.html>{contentElement.bodytext}</f:format.html>
                </f:for>
</v:content.render>
```